# How to add a HistogramChart with the Google API Spread Sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, charts, google-api

I'm trying to create a Histogram Chart by following the [Charts Sheet API Docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#ChartSourceRange).
I'm still getting this error, linked to the sourceRange : **Details: "Invalid requests[0].addChart: ChartSourceRange ranges require all rows or all columns to have length of 1**

Here the table data :

| Name | 15/06 | 16/06 | 17/06 | 20/06 | 21/06 | 22/06 | 23/06 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4000 | 3812 | 3941 | 3734 | 3868 | 3815 | 3860 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 99 | 96 | 98 | 120 | 109 | 95 | 98 |
| D | 425 | 569 | 604 | 476 | 433 | 514 | 897 |
| E | 76 | 87 | 139 | 82 | 167 | 162 | 178 |
| F | 26 | 14 | 22 | 18 | 14 | 84 | 0 |

Here the graph I would like to have :
[image]

And here the request I've started to realize:

```
request_chart = {
    'requests' : [
        {
            'addChart' : {
                'chart' : {
                    'spec' : {
                        'title' : 'En nombre',
                        'histogramChart' : {
                            "showItemDividers": False,
                            'legendPosition' : 'RIGHT_LEGEND',
                            'series' : [
                                {
                                    'data': {
                                        'sourceRange':{
                                            'sources': [
                                                {
                                                    "sheetId": 0,
                                                    "startRowIndex": 1,
                                                    "endRowIndex": 7,
                                                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                                                    "endColumnIndex": 8,
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    'position' : {
                    'newSheet' : True
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

service_sheets.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId = id_fichier_historique, body = request_chart).execute()
return
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: What kind of chart are you looking to create? I am asking because in your code you are trying to create a histogram type but the one you show in the picture looks like a stacked column chart. The error you are getting is also related to the number of columns you are trying to get. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#chartsourcerange) shows you can only get a range of 1.

Comment: Hi @FernandoLara. When I realised the chart you see in the picture on google sheet, it was called : "stacked histogram". That why I chose this one in my code. I may be wrong !

Comment: Hello! Just for clarification I wanted to make sure if your end goal is to get the exact same chart from the picture because in Google Sheets that one is called "Stacked column chart", that way I can make the needed changes to the request since it is a bit different. The histogram chart looks very different because the columns are all next to each other and to my understanding there is no option to create a stacked histogram chart neither from the web UI or APIs, but the one from the picture is achievable so just need to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to create the exact same chart from the picture, then the request should go like this:

```
'requests' : [
        {
            'addChart' : {
                'chart' : {
                    'spec' : {
                        'title' : 'Number',
                        'basicChart' : {
                            "chartType": "COLUMN",
                            'legendPosition' : 'RIGHT_LEGEND',
                            'domains' : [
                                {
                                    'domain' : {
                                        'sourceRange':{
                                            'sources': [
                                                {
                                                    "sheetId": 0,
                                                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                                                    "endRowIndex": 1,
                                                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                                                    "endColumnIndex": 8
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            'series' : [
                                {
                                    "series": {
                                        "sourceRange": {
                                            "sources": [
                                                {
                                                    "sheetId": 0,
                                                    "startRowIndex": 1,
                                                    "endRowIndex": 2,
                                                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                                                    "endColumnIndex": 8
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                },
                                {
                                    "series": {
                                        "sourceRange": {
                                            "sources": [
                                                {
                                                    "sheetId": 0,
                                                    "startRowIndex": 2,
                                                    "endRowIndex": 3,
                                                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                                                    "endColumnIndex": 8
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                },
                                {
                                    "series": {
                                        "sourceRange": {
                                            "sources": [
                                                {
                                                    "sheetId": 0,
                                                    "startRowIndex": 3,
                                                    "endRowIndex": 4,
                                                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                                                    "endColumnIndex": 8
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                },
                                {
                                    "series": {
                                        "sourceRange": {
                                            "sources": [
                                                {
                                                    "sheetId": 0,
                                                    "startRowIndex": 4,
                                                    "endRowIndex": 5,
                                                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                                                    "endColumnIndex": 8
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                },
                                {
                                    "series": {
                                        "sourceRange": {
                                            "sources": [
                                                {
                                                    "sheetId": 0,
                                                    "startRowIndex": 5,
                                                    "endRowIndex": 6,
                                                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                                                    "endColumnIndex": 8
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                },
                                {
                                    "series": {
                                        "sourceRange": {
                                            "sources": [
                                                {
                                                    "sheetId": 0,
                                                    "startRowIndex": 6,
                                                    "endRowIndex": 7,
                                                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                                                    "endColumnIndex": 8
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                },
                            ],
                            "headerCount": 1,
                            "stackedType": "STACKED"
                        }
                    },
                    'position' : {
                    'newSheet' : True
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

The error you were getting was because the length of the `sourceRange` sources should be 1 as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#chartsourcerange:%7E:text=The%20ranges%20of%20data%20for%20a%20series%20or%20domain.%20Exactly%20one%20dimension%20must%20have%20a%20length%20of%201%2C%20and%20all%20sources%20in%20the%20list%20must%20have%20the%20same%20dimension%20with%20length%201).

> The ranges of data for a series or domain. Exactly one dimension must have a length of 1, and all sources in the list must have the same dimension with length 1.

If you see, you have to add multiple sources in the request, and you were merging all the sources in a single source, that is why you were getting that specific error.

Output:
[image]

References:

- [ChartSourceRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#chartsourcerange)
- [ChartSpec](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#chartspec)
- [Charts Google Sheets APIs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fernando Lara. It's exactly what I was looking for !